# getting a batch file to open the next file before the last one is closed

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I've never had this happen before and I've used dozens of batch files before so I'm stumped. I'm executing the batch on windows 7.

My batch file reads exactly as follows:

```
"C:\Users\MYOB\Desktop\ISSP Project\Learning Objectives.docx"    
"c:\users\MYOB\desktop\comp\unit2.pdf"    
"C:\Users\MYOB\Desktop\course.bat"
```

What I would like is for all three files to open up. The behaviour I get is that the first file will open, the command prompt window will remain open with the text showing the execution line visible, and until I close the file that was just opened the next one will not open.

This behaviour seems to specifically relate to PDF files, I can open a hundred at a time of any other filetype, but for a pdf it waits for me to close the first file.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `start` like this

```
start "" "C:\Users\MYOB\Desktop\ISSP Project\Learning Objectives.docx"    
start "" "c:\users\MYOB\desktop\comp\unit2.pdf"    
start "" "C:\Users\MYOB\Desktop\course.bat"
```

Although the blank quotes aren't strictly necessary for the last 2, it will save you getting caught out if you add more that have spaces in the path.

Comment: Thank-you @Bali C this is exactly what I needed. 

I saw the solution before but thought to myself, I already have Acro32 as the default for pdf, why would I need to use start? 

I'll mark it as correct as soon as the time limit has elapsed.